# MongoDB принимает за _id свойство Id

Tags: c#, mongodb

Как указать `MongoDB`, что `Id` это не `_id` в данном классе

```
class A
{
  SomethingClass Id;
  ...
}
```

,где `SomethingClass`:

```
class SomethingClass
{
  int i;
  int j;
  int k;
}
```

добавляю строку в БД так:

```
mongoCollection.InsertOne(item);
```

в базе запись появляется вида:

```
{ "_id" : { "i": 5, "j": 6, "k":10}, .... }
```

не хотелось бы, чтобы `MongoDB` считал это свойство за идентификатор с БД. Сложность в том, что этот класс содержится в библиотеке, менять его нельзя.

Comment: Может не стоит сохранять класс, которым вы не управляете? Что если автор библиотеки этот класс изменит или удалит? ИМХО, надо делать свой прокси и его писать в БД

Comment: Если автор изменит этот класс, то я это узнаю (build поменяется) и очищу данные, если удалит, то и скомпилировать проект я не смогу, так что вопрос остается открытым.

Comment: Вы все классы при новом билде будете проверять, что там автор добавит\изменит? Я к тому, что ваша основная потенциальная проблема в том, что вы не контролируете сущности, что сохраняете в БД. Когда начнете контролировать и сохранять свои классы в БД, то проблемы из вопроса у вас уже не будет.

Comment: Задача стоит при конкретном классе, переобарачивать, то что мне приходит извне мне не интересно и очень муторно. Пусть это будет 100500 классов со свойством id, мне что их всех переопределять? я свихнусь. Мне нужно драйверу MongoDB сказать, чтоб он не считал Id за _id и всё. Мне не нужно контролировать изменился ли референс класса, в данном случае мне это не интересно. Тем более если класс запечатан.

Comment: А какой библиотекой пользуетесь для работы с `MongoDB`? Там есть возможность переопределения имен свойств через атрибуты?

Comment: .Net библиотекой, распростроняемой MongoDB. (MongoDB.Bson). Я назначил BSONKnownType, а вот с Id не пойму как

Comment: Попробуйте использовать атрибут `[BsonElement("somethingclass_id")]`

Comment: я не могу добавить атрибут в класс который поставляется в библиотеке, в том то и дело, так бы я уже использовал бы BsonNoIdAttribute

Comment: Я не спец в монге, но, мне кажется, вам надо будет поработать с [BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/bson/mapping/) (как [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45641785/312041))

Comment: @tym32167 отличный пример переопределения Id, то что нужно. Спасибо.

Comment: @tym32167 Добавьте, как ответ `BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<B>(p => p.AutoMap(); p.UnmapProperty(c => c.Id); p.MapMember(c => c.Id).SetElementName(); p.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true);`

Comment: Добавил, хотя вы за меня ответ написали по сути :)

Comment: @tym32167 считаю, что ответ Ваш.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<B>(p => 
{
    p.AutoMap(); 
    p.UnmapProperty(c => c.Id); 
    p.MapMember(c => c.Id).SetElementName(); 
    p.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true);
}
```

Подробнее про [BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/bson/mapping/)